# 301 Redirect directory and any possible files therein to new directory

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect an old directory, all possibly sub-directories, and all possible files all to one new directory.

Redirect anything such as:

- .com/old
- .com/old/older
- .com/old/index.php
- .com/old/older/index.php

and so on all should redirect to .com/new

I've tried several .htaccess generators and tutorials, and I get a very mixed baskets of results.

For example, the most common problem I get is that .com/old/older/index.php will redirect to .com/new/older/index.php instead of just .com/new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this simple 301 rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/old(/.*)?$ /new
```

Or else use this rule in `/old/.htaccess` file:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^ /new
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. In the case of old files, this seems to also redirect to the new directory while trying to load the file. Trying .com/old/file.php leads to .com/new/file.php instead of just going to .com/new

Comment: You might be having old cache in your browser. Clear your browser cache completely and then test it.

Comment: Cleared the cache, waited a bit, and even cleared the DNS cache in chrome for overkill, and it seems to now be working as intended. Much thanks.